# Adding subrecords in an Access table

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on creating an Access database used to keep track of my workout progress.

For the moment, I have 2 tables:

**Training_Session:**

```
Date  
Start_Time  
End_Time  
Total_Time
```

**Exercise:**

```
Type  
Weight  
Repetition
```

The table exercise would contain the exercise I did for a particular session. I wanted to upload an image I took of the database I'm trying to produce but for some reason I can't use the upload image feature and I need 5 reputation to ask on meta.

Basically, it would look like:

```
  Date1       | Start1    | End1   | Total1  
- Exercise1.1 | Weight1.1 | Rep1.1  
- Exercise1.2 | Weight1.2 | Rep1.2  
- ...  
  Date2       | Start2    | End2   | Total2   
- Exercise2.1 | Weight2.1 | Rep2.1  
- Exercise2.2 | Weight2.2 | Rep2.2  
- ...  
...
```

Like with a subdatasheet. The only thing is that the tables are unrelated, there's no field that could be used to link them together.

Is it possible to insert a "different" table exercise into each record of the table training_session?

Comment: You should make this easier on yourself. Add an AutoNumber field as a key to each of your tables, then add a third table that relates to the two tables you already have. That table then should contain as many exercises for any date as you need.

Comment: If each date can have multiple exercises and each exercise can have with multiple dates, then you have a many-to-many relationship. As Wayne describes, this requires a third 'junction' table of records that associate dates with exercises.

Comment: I don't think it is a many to many relationship. Each record of `Exercise` belongs to a single record of `Training_Session`. You just need to add ID fields to the tables like Wayne G. Dunn suggested and then add an additional field to the `Exercise` table for the ID of the `Training_Session` record it belongs to.